# React Native Apollo Client doesn't fetch all data

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I have the following query:

```
query(abc: 1) {
  id
  level1 {
    id
    level2 {
      level3a {
        id
      }
      level3b {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my browser (using GraphiQL) everything returns fine, but when I try to run the exact same query on my Apollo Client it returns null for level2.

```
client.query({query: myQuery}).then((resp) => {
```

This is how I'm using it, any idea on why it's returning null on the client?

If any more information is needed, let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why, but running:

```
client.query({query: myQuery, fetchPolicy: "no-cache"})
```

I'm guessing deep objects can't be cached.. If anyone can add an explanation I'll edit it in. Thank you